# snap.svg save element and paste it to another

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I create some lines in my Paper:

```
var svg = Snap("#svg_container");
var linesContainer = {};

var line = svg.line( 0, 0, 200, 200).attr(...);
linesContainer[someID] = line;
```

then i clear the Snap / create a new. I want to  have the stored object also in my new snap:

```
svg = Snap("#svg_container");
svg.clear();

//something like:
//svg.append(linesContainer[someID]);
```

is this possible?

Comment: If you store the lines in a set, you could remove the line you want from the set (and store in a separate one), and then do a set.clear() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here script with using SnapSVG.

```
var linesContainer = []; // not {}
lineContainer[linesContainer.length] = svg.line( 0, 0, 200, 200).attr(...); 
// or 2nd way .. u can definitely make objects with value x,y, attrs  and store them, but it helps reducing a storage of using memory.
```

U can put line to svg like that.

```
svg = Snap("#svg_container");
svg.clear();
for(i=0;i<lineContainer.length;i++)
    svg.add(lineContainer[i]);
```

Comment: Will probably eventually work, but there's quite a few bugs in that code.